# Chef: gem dependency on provider

Tags: chef-infra

We're creating a provider for a resource. It stands for creating a mongo user into given database.

```
class LivingMongoCookbook::UserProvider < Chef::Provider::LWRPBase 
  provides :living_mongo_user
  def whyrun_supported?
   true
  end
  def action_create
   db = Mongo::Connection.new(new_resource.host, new_resource.port).db(new_resource.database)
   users = db.getUsers
   db.createUser({ user: new_resource.user, pwd: new_resource.passwd, roles: [ new_resource.roles ]})
   new_resource.updated_by_last_action(true)
 end
end
```

We're lokking to use mongo ruby driver in order to be able to create user on db. Nevertheless, we're getting this message:

```
================================================================================
  Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/living_mongo/libraries/provider_user.rb
   ================================================================================       LoadError
  ---------
  cannot load such file -- mongo       Cookbook Trace:
  ---------------
    /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/living_mongo/libraries/provider_user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'       Relevant File Content:
  ----------------------
  /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/living_mongo/libraries/provider_user.rb:         1>> require 'mongo'
    2:
    3:  # Chef Provider for creating a user and group for Elasticsearch
    4:  class LivingMongoCookbook::UserProvider < Chef::Provider::LWRPBase
    5:
    6:    provides :living_mongo_user
    7:
    8:    def whyrun_supported?
    9:      true
   10:    end
```

It seems like mongo driver is not available.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a `chef_gem 'mongo'`with `compile_time true` so it gets the gem installed into chef(s ruby before your provider run (See [chef_gem](https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html) documentation)

Comment: Ho, and at a point you'll have to `require 'mongo'`  before calling its class...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a recent-ish Chef version and the gem doesn't require a C compiler, add `gem 'mongo'` to the `metadata.rb` and Chef will take care of installing it for you.